# Returning Null on insert in case of partition in postgres

Tags: postgresql

When I insert a record I need to return the inserted id in case of partition tables in postgres. What is the best approach to do so to achieve the best performance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you want a returning clause on an update, you can use `UPDATE ... RETURNING ...`.
You might find [this documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html) usefull.